# Cannot Import .snk file error in TFS build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild, code-signing

In the signing tab in Visual Studio I've checked "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" (.pfx) and "Sign the assembly" (.snk).

On my build machine I've installed the .pfx certificate.

The .snk does **not** have a password

I don't understand why I'm having issues with the SNK file?

[image]

So the file isn't password protected, and you can't import an snk file into a personal certificate store...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the build account wasn't running under the same account that I was importing the certificate under.

What was misleading is that it was complaining about the snk file when the real issue was the pfx.